# Wait On Event listener complete in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dnsbl

I use a node package `'dnsbl-lookup'` to check blacklist domains.

However, when I pass an array of domains to `'dnsbl-lookup'` for checking, `'dnsbl-lookup'` `on events` not waiting all `Eventlistener` complete, instead it return empty array.

How can I let all items get checked complete then return `resultsArr` array.

```
const lookup = require("dnsbl-lookup");

    const checkDomainsBlacklist = async (req, res, next) => {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return next(new HttpError("Invalid domain list", 422));
      }
    
      const { domains} = req.body;
      let resultsArr = [];

      for (let index = 0; index < domains.length; index++) {
        const domain= domains[index].trim();
        let checkCount = 0;
        let dnsbl = new lookup.dnsbl(domain, blockLists); 
        //`blockLists` => list of sites to validate domain blacklist

        dnsbl.on("error", function (error, blocklist) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    
        dnsbl.on("data", function (result, blocklist) {
          checkCount++;
          console.log(result.status + " in " + blocklist.zone);
    
          if (result.status === "listed") {
            let result = {
              url: domain,
              blUrl: blocklist.zone,
            };
            resultsArr.push(result);
          }
        });
    
        dnsbl.on("done", function () {
          console.log("lookup finished");
        });
      }
    
      res.status(202).json({ resultsArr: resultsArr });
    };
```

Comment: Use promises and `await`.

Comment: I tried to add then() but it does not have then function

Comment: You should consider moving this line `res.status(202).json({ resultsArr: resultsArr });` inside the handler for `done` event. Your code is not waiting for the process to finish.

Comment: Did you create the promise with `new Promise()` so you'll have something to wait on?

Comment: @Barmar, let me do research your suggestion, thanks. Please anything else I need to take care of ?

Comment: In general, waiting for an event in a loop seems like wrong design in JS. You can create the event listeners in the loop, then the listeners should operate independently.

Comment: Seem like complicated for me. One more question, do you know other library I can depend on to verify domain blacklist or way to do that ?